# SQL queries to select data from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as follows:

table1:

```
user_id     ancestry
---------   ----------
1        England
1        Ireland
2        France
3        Germany
3        Poland
4        England
4        France
4        Germany
5        France
5        Germany
```

table2:

```
country     
---------   
England
Germany
France
```

I need to write a sql query that will pick out all those User ID  who has ancestry every country in the table2.How Can I achive that.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried thus far?

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` is need in case one `user_id` can have multiple ancestry from same country

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM  Table1
GROUP  BY user_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ancestry) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2)
```

**EDIT:** 
I realize `table1` can have different countries than `table2` like `Ireland`.

So you probably need use `JOIN` to see how many match exists

```
SELECT T1.user_id 
FROM  Table1 T1
JOIN  Table2 T2
  ON  T1.ancestry = T2.country
GROUP BY T1.user_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT T1.ancestry) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2)
```

Comment: Thank you.It is working properly.IS there any other way I can do it?

Comment: If already solve your problem what you want another solution?